# Offline Resources on Dynamic Data and Entity Framework

Tags: .net, asp.net, entity-framework, dynamic-data

Horrors, I'm stuckk with only 3G access to the net, so I would like to download some solid references to Entity Framework and Dynamic Data that I can get by with while offline, as I'm no expert on these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can "download" these from amazon ... though the transport protocol usually takes 3-5 days to finish "downloading".

- [Dynamic Data](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_ss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=ADO.NET+Dynamic+Data&x=0&y=0)
- [Entity Framework](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_ss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=Entity+Framework&x=0&y=0)

;-)